# What's the natural way to say it sounds + adjective in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, syntax

So for example:

*That sounds scary to me.*

Google translates it as

それは私に恐ろしいと思う。

Does that sound natural in Japanese?

Thanks.

Comment: What the users here want to see is your own translation attempt and not Google's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to put it simple and basic,

**い-adjectives; adjective - the last い + そう**

for example:

- こわい(scary)　→　こわそう(looks/sounds[would be] scary)
- おいしい(delicious)　→　おいしそう(looks/sounds [would be] good)
- おもい(heavy)　→　おもそう(looks/sounds [would be] heavy)

> この映画はとても怖そうです！
>   This movie looks very scary!

---

**な-adjectives; adjective + そう**

for example:

- きれい(beautiful, clean)　→　きれいそう(looks/sounds[would be] beautiful/clean)
- げんき(vital, healthy)　→　げんきそう(looks/sounds [would be] vital, healthy)
- たいへん(dreadful, terrible)　→　たいへんそう(looks/sounds [would be] dreadful/terrible)

> あなたは元気そうですね。
>   You seem to be in good spirit.

Comment: 勉強になりました、ありがとうございます。